How to increase resolution of turtle screen in Python?
I use the code turtle.setup(600, 600) and it fills 70% of my desktop. I want to make this smaller but still maintaining the 600x600 turtle screen.
I tried to use turtle.screensize(canvwidth=600, canvheight=600, bg="white") but still the same output.

How can you make 600x600 smaller? 600 pixels is always 600 pixels. This question sounds like "I want to be shorter while still maintaining my height of 6 feet" which is impossible.

What I'm guessing you want is setworldcoordinates() which will allow you to manipulate the screen geometry without the turtle knowing what you're up to:
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=300, height=300)
screen.setworldcoordinates(-300, -300, 300, 300)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.sety(-300)
turtle.circle(300)

screen.exitonclick()

Here the turtle thinks its drawing a 600 pixel diameter circle but on the screen it will be half that size.
However, another interpretation of your request might be to allow the turtle to draw 1:1 using half the window but still being able to access the full drawing.  That's what we use screensize() for:
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=300, height=300)
screen.screensize(canvwidth=600, canvheight=600)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.sety(-300)
turtle.circle(300)

screen.exitonclick()

Full size drawing, half size window, but you're able to scroll around it to see the entire drawing.
